# probability almost different and expectation

Tags: probability-theory

This relates to my question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1248232/probability-almost-surely-and-expectation), but for the difference case, i.e. is it true that $P(X \ne Y)=1 \Rightarrow E(X) \ne E(Y)$?

I tried using the same proof technique as the answers to my other question but failed to prove it for an hour. In fact the claim in the other question follows since $0 =\mathbf{P} (X \leqslant 0) =\mathbf{P} (X^- > 0) +\mathbf{P} (X^+ = X^-)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is false.  Suppose $X$ is uniformly distributed in the interval $[0,1]$ and $Y=1-X$.  Or that $X\sim N(0,1)$ and $Y=-X$.  Or that $X\sim\mathrm{Bernoulli}(1/2)$ and $Y=1-X$.  Or that $X,Y\sim\text{i.i.d. }\mathrm{Exponential}(1)$.  In each of these cases, $X$ has the same distribution, and hence the same expected value as $Y$, and in each of these cases, $\Pr(X\ne Y)=1$.